# How to share multiple file via UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to implement share multiple file to `Facebook` , `mail` ,`google driver` and `whatsapp`.

I can share one file via `UIDocumentInteractionController` like the following code:

```
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directory, [fileList objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row]] ;
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePath] ;

    documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    [documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
    documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    [documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

How to share multiple file via `UIDocumentInteractionController` without using `UIActivityViewController` ?

If use `NSMutableArray` , and add multiple object of `url`. How to set `NSMutableArray` to `UIDocumentInteractionController` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To share multiple files you can use UIActivityViewController.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:self.imgView.image.CGImage];

NSArray* dataToShare = @[image, image2, image3];  // Any data you want to share.

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This might help you.

Comment: So the `UIDocumentInteractionController` can not share multiple files ?

Comment: According to documentation 

"A document interaction controller, along with a delegate object, provides in-app support for managing user interactions with files in the local system. For example, an email program might use this class to allow the user to preview attachments and open them in other apps. Use this class to present an appropriate user interface for previewing, opening, copying, or printing a specified file." 

So only one file can be shared among two apps using UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: For me, the suggested UIActivityViewController approach works just fine in iOS 8.4 for sharing multiple files as Email attachments.  However, certain app icons (like Dropbox) only appear when sharing a single file.